# Subprocess.check_output fails with exit status -15

Tags: python, subprocess

```
subprocess.check_output('lspci | egrep  -i "virtio network" | wc -l', shell=True)
```

Is failing with exit status -15. What could be the possible scenarios for this to happen?

```
CalledProcessError: Command 'lspci | egrep  -i "virtio network" | wc -l' returned non-zero exit status -15
```

I read about exit status 1 but what is the specific meaning behind code -15.

Comment: Can you run that in your command line?
Try running it in the command line and do a 
$ echo $? 
after it to look at the return value and see if it is the same.

Comment: Your command works fine in Ubuntu 18 (Python3). What is the environment where the error occurs?

Comment: @Hannu It's non-reproducible. It happened in production environment. VM was on GCP.

Answer (score 1):

You would see this in python 2, if the the subprocess died having received `SIGTERM` (i.e. `15`). Since you've used `shell=True`, this mean the `/bin/sh` process wrapping your call got killed with (received signal) `SIGTERM` (and terminated).

Python 3 output would be perhaps a bit more helpful as to hinting the cause in this case:

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'lspci | egrep  -i "virtio network" | wc -l' died with <Signals.SIGTERM: 15>.
```

Looking at your line:

```
subprocess.check_output('lspci | egrep  -i "virtio network" | wc -l', shell=True)
```

Perhaps it would make sense to try this:

```
len([l for l
     in subprocess.check_output('lspci').lower().splitlines()
     if b"virtio network" in l])
```

Instead of wrapping the call in a shell instance and forking multiple processes to get number of lines with certain string, it retrieves output from `lspci`, converts it to lower case (to make the matches case insensitive like `-i` above) and splits the output on line boundaries. List comprehension based on the list of those lines gets us a resulting list of all lines limited to those containing the searched for `str` (or rather `bytes` to be py2/3 friendly) and `len` gives us an `int` of how many such lines there were.